# Independence of two (discrete) Random Variables

Tags: probability

We know that for two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ to be independent, the joint density of random vector $Z=(X,Y)$ has to be equal to product of marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$.

Now, this means:

a) To establish independence of $X$ and $Y$, we gotta test the above equality for every vector of euclidean plane.

b) To establish independence of $X$ and $Y$, we can test the above equality for only one vector of euclidean plane, and this suffices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For discrete random variables taking on finite sets of values, the joint probability mass function can be viewed as a *matrix* $P_{X,Y}$ with, say $m$ rows and $n$ columns, while the marginal mass functions can be viewed as $1\times m$ and $1\times n$ matrices (row vectors) $P_X$ and $P_Y$. Independence requires you to check whether $P_{X,Y} = P_X^TP_Y$, and this requires you to verify this matrix equality (that is, check whether the entries are all the same on both sides). So, $m\times n$ tests.

Comment: Got it. Many thanks. Naturally, if both are equally distributed, it would suffice to test for a single point, right?

Comment: `Naturally, if both are equally distributed, it would suffice to test for a single point, right?`  **Absolutely not; you have to test at each and every point.**  Consider the case of two random variables with $$P_{X,Y}=\left[\matrix{\frac{2}{9} & 0 & \frac{1}{9}\\0&\frac{1}{3}&0\\\frac{1}{9}&0&\frac{2}{9}}\right]$$ and $P_X = P_Y = [\frac13, \frac13, \frac13]$ for which $P_{X,Y}(i,j) = P_X(i)P_Y(j)$ holds for some choices of $i$ and $j$ and not for others. If you test at one point where equality holds, you arrive at the wrong conclusion.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this later. Thanks a lot.